# Scraping website in Python that uses CSS to populate content

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape data from the Profile and Results tab under kaggle.com/users.

I have worked with BeautifulSoup before and know how to get to links for individual users, and to navigate to them. However, by default, only the Profile tab is populated. The Results tab content is dynamically populated only once a user clicks on it.

If you look under the div with id 'profile2-content', each div underneath corresponds to content of one tab, but all but one of those sub-tabs have style set to display: none.

Once I get to the Profile tab of each user (as default), how do I then get the Results content to be loaded. Once that's done, I can probably look for the fixed div with id 'profile2-content-results' and extract its contents.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What´s your code know? What doesn't work? What information do you want to crawl from what page

Comment: @VincentBeltman I am looking to extract the HTML under the Profile and Results divs

Answer (score 0):

It's loaded using ajax, from the following url: kaggle.com/knockout/profiles/{user_id}/results

I would suggest you open up firebug/chrome dev tools and click around pages with the network tab open, to see what they load dynamically.

Comment: I saw that through the network requests in firebug. However, I want the HTML within the the result div, not the JSON data available at http://www.kaggle.com/knockout/profiles/{user_id}/results. So I need to get the page to render and then scrape the HTML

Comment: Or can I use mechanize and follow_link() to follow the link with the word 'Results' and then extract the HTML? There's only one link on the page with text 'Results'.